# Load list of objects into function - R solution

Tags: r

I'm getting myself quite confused! I have some files all with the same extension and I want to load them into individual objects (I can do this part). I then have a function, and I want to take the argument of that function to be all the objects I've just created...

In my working directory I have 2 files:

```
A.hist
B.hist
```

Now I load them into objects:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.hist")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

Now I have 2 objects: `A.hist` and `B.hist`

I have a function whereby I want to make a histogram:

```
plot_histogram <- function(data) {
  
  ggplot(data, aes(V2, V5)) + geom_col() + xlim(0,500) + ylim(0,0.01)+
    ylab("Proportion") + xlab("Read Depth")
  
}
```

What I want to do is parse each of the objects I've made (and only these) into the `data` argument of my function in essence I want to end up with:

```
ggplot(A.hist, aes(V2, V5)) + geom_col() + xlim(0,500) + ylim(0,0.01)+
    ylab("Proportion") + xlab("Read Depth")
```

and

```
ggplot(B.hist, aes(V2, V5)) + geom_col() + xlim(0,500) + ylim(0,0.01)+
    ylab("Proportion") + xlab("Read Depth")
```

I assume I need to use an `apply` function but I have to confess I get very confused here. If someone can help me parse in my objects into my function, I'd be really grateful!

Comment: out <- lapply(temp, read.csv) seems a million times better than your current approach.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see that gives me a list of both of the dataframes. What I can't figure out is how I then apply the function to that list...

Comment: Or is it as simple as lapply(out, plot_histogram) ?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it... it's probably not the most elegant solution, but it works..

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.hist")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.table(temp[i]))
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.table)

plot_histogram <- function(x) {
  
  x <- ggplot(x, aes(V2, V5)) + geom_col() + xlim(0,500) + ylim(0,0.01)+
    ylab("Proportion") + xlab("Read Depth")

}

lapply(myfiles, plot_histogram)
```

Comment: I think the for loop is unnecessary